# How to see files in Windows Server from Ubuntu using VPN

Tags: windows, vpn, file-sharing

I am really new with Ubuntu but I am really looking forward to keeping learning.

When I was using Windows 10 I would connect to my work network via VPN and then I was able to access a server with a repository I need to clone to my personal computer. The way I would access on Windows, once connected to the VPN, was something like "\[server IP]\Folder\Repository\This is the folder I want".

Now, in Ubuntu 18.04 I was able to connect to the VPN by just creating it and entering my credentials. I would like to clarify that I can ping the server and it works fine. I mean, I am correctly connected through the VPN. The problem begins when I try to get to the "\[server IP]\Folder\Repository\This is the folder I want" path. I went to the files manager and in Networks I can see a folder called "Windows Network" but when I double click I see the message "Unable to access location// Failed to retrieve share list from server: no such file or directory. Then, above, I can see a box called "Connect to Server" but when I go to the Available Protocols I have no idea which one to use.

I am little bit at a loss here. Could you please throw some light on me about this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use the samba protocol. You can enter `smb://ip/path/to/share` as well.

Comment: That was completely it! Before, I tried `smb://ip/` and that would give me an error.

Thanks a lot vidarlo! I think this is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Once you are connected to the server network through VPN you can access the file by clicking "**connect to server**"  then use " **smb://ip/file/shared file location**".